# American Developer account in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, account

I am a Russian developer with personal developer account and I can publish my apps easily. Now Now I want to get an USA dev acc for some testing reasons and I don't now where to start. What do I need - an american adress, credit card or what? Any succces stories from developers from other countries who made it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dutch developer here, I was simply able to use my mother's credit card (back then I was too young to have a CC, and I still haven't got one, lol).

As far as I know you don't need to have any kind of special settings to have a developer account. Unless, of course, Apple doesn't have a presence in Russia, in which case you should find someone with an american address and an american credit card.

Comment: I must agree with Tom. I'm also a dutch developer and my apos are available in every country that the app store is available. What are the needs for a specifiek American account?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and what about american Apple ID? It's required for installing of some apps. So I thought that there is a difference. As you say, american credit card is only thing that needed for getting Aplle ID or I missed the point?

Comment: I didn't need a Credit Card for that either - I was able to use ClickAndBuy, which was able to use my bank account.